# use route parameter in the Redux Saga file

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux-saga

How to pass current route parameters to the saga function?

[image]

```
// Saga
 function* findOneReleaseWithFilesSaga() {
   const { productName, releaseId } = useParams()
   try {
     const releaseResponse: AxiosResponse = yield call(findOneWithFiles, releaseId)
                                                       ^^^Error Here^^^
     yield put(getAllReleasesSuccessAction(releaseResponse))
   } catch (error) {
     yield put(getAllReleasesErrorAction(error))
   }
 }

// Fetch Data
 export const findOneWithFiles = async (releaseId:string) => {
   return await Api.get(`/releases/${releaseId}/?populate=data_files`)
     .then((res) => res.data.data)
     .catch((err) => err)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in the type of `releaseId` you get from `useParams`. Make sure it is a string. Also the desctructuring might be a problem, there were some fixes for that in TS4.6, but assuming you are on older version I would try to assign to a variable instead:

```
const params = useParams()
yield call(findOneWithFiles, params.releaseId)
```

On a side note, I would avoid prefixing a function with `use` unless it is a react hook.